# Exclude current post but keep the same posts-per_page amount

Tags: customization, loop

Okay I have a custom loop within the main loop of the page that shows 4 posts but obviously excludes the current main post. I'll show you:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=3&posts_per_page=4" );
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        if($post->ID == $mainPost) continue; ?>
        <?php get_template_part('workThumb'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

However I want to show 4 posts in this loop but obviously if it contains the current post then it only shows 3. However if I increase the posts_per_page to 5 then on pages when it doesn't include the current post it shows 5 posts, which I don't want.

I hope this makes sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query to:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array("cat" => 3, "posts_per_page" => 4, "post__not_in" => array($mainPost)));
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Woop! Yes man you're a genius! Thank you very much.